# Creating a netsuite record as a particular custom form

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom form for the 'customerdeposit' record.  I want to create a record with the fields from that form.  What would the best way be to do that?  I have seen a method to create it, set the customform field, save it, open it again, set the field values, and then save it again.  Is there a better way?

```
var drec = nlapiCreateRecord('customerdeposit');
drec.setFieldValue('customForm', 162);
var tmp = nlapiSubmitRecord(drec, true);
var drec = nlapiLoadRecord('customerdeposit', tmp);
drec.setFieldValue('fieldfromcustomform', value);
nlapiSubmitRecord(drec, true);
```

edit: 
after trying a bit more poking, it was simply a setFieldValue vs. setFieldValues issue that coincidentally occurred at the point where I started setting 'custbody_xxx' fields.  Open/close was not necessary.

Comment: so why to `submit` and `load` again? you can directly create a record and map all the field values that you wanted to be in your custom record and just submit it.

Comment: The vanilla 'customerdeposit' record does not contain the fields that I need to populate.  Those fields are added by the custom form.  Therefore, I am looking for a way to create a record with the fields from the custom form initially, so i can do as you say.

Comment: How did you create this custom field? In scripts, the form does not determine what fields are available on the record. If you've created your custom field as a custom Transaction Body field, then that field is available through script, regardless of the form being used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic mode while creating the record to replicate the UI way of setting the fields.

nlapiCreateRecord('salesorder', {recordmode: 'dynamic'});

Comment: I know I am not supposed to just say thanks, but this would have saved me hours of work translating a users description of action into code (and will pay of in the future, for sure)!